# spring-data Specification and joined subquery

Tags: jpa-2.0, spring-data-jpa, criteria-api, named-query

I have the following Named query on my spring-data repository:

`@Query("FROM Pedido p JOIN FETCH p.status ps WHERE ps.status IN (?1) AND ps.id IN (SELECT MAX(ps2.id) FROM PedidoStatus ps2 GROUP BY ps2.pedido)")`

I'm trying to achieve the same result using the Criteria API and spring-data Specifications, this is what I have so far:

```
public static Specification<Pedido> byUltimoStatus(final List<PedidoStatus.StatusPedido> ultimoStatus) {
return new Specification<Pedido>() {
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Pedido> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder) {

        Expression<PedidoStatus.StatusPedido> status = root.join("status").get("status");
        Predicate predicateByStatus = status.in(ultimoStatus);

        final Subquery<Long> subQuery = query.subquery(Long.class);
        final Root<PedidoStatus> ps = subQuery.from(PedidoStatus.class);

        Expression<Long> psId= ps.get("id");
        Expression<Long> maxId = builder.max(psId);

        subQuery.select(maxId);
        subQuery.groupBy(ps.get("pedido").get("id"));

        Predicate predicateByUltimoStatus = builder.in(root.join("status").get("id")).value(subQuery);

        return builder.and(predicateByStatus, predicateByUltimoStatus);             
    }
};}
```

It's still not working, looks like there is an extra 
`INNERJOIN PedidoStatus`
in the result query.

This is the result of the @Query:

```
select ... from Pedido pedido0_ inner join PedidoStatus status1_ on pedido0_.id=status1_.pedido where (status1_.status in (? , ?)) and (status1_.id in (select max(pedidostat2_.id) from PedidoStatus pedidostat2_ group by pedidostat2_.pedido))
```

And this is the result of the Criteria API:

```
select ... from Pedido pedido0_ inner join PedidoStatus status1_ on pedido0_.id=status1_.pedido inner join PedidoStatus status2_ on pedido0_.id=status2_.pedido where (pedido0_.id is not null) and status1_.status IN (?, ?) and (status2_.id in (select max(pedidostat3_.id) from PedidoStatus pedidostat3_ group by pedidostat3_.pedido))
```

Comment: Did you found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Knowing that this is a very old question, it looks to me like the reason for the duplicate INNERJOIN in the query generated by a CriteriaQuery is that the code building the query, does actually invoke `root.join("status")` twice. The result of the first invocation should be saved into a local variable, so you can reuse it, instead of joining twice.

First you do:

> `Expression<PedidoStatus.StatusPedido> status = root.join("status").get("status");`

And later you do:

> `Predicate predicateByUltimoStatus = builder.in(root.join("status").get("id")).value(subQuery);`